# Setting variables inside IF/ELSE statement in Windows CMD batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've simple cmd script:

```
@echo off
if  %1.==. (
    echo Missing argument
) else (
    SET somevar=%1
    echo %1
    echo %somevar%
)
```

Problem with that is it looks like echo of variable `somevar` in else block are running before variable is set. Every time I run this, echo of argument working well but echo of variable shows value from previous run. This is happening only in if/else block and I don't understand why. If I modify script like that:

```
@echo off
if  %1.==. (
    echo Missing argument
    exit /B
)

SET somevar=%1
echo %1
echo %somevar%
```

result is as I expected. Running the script alternately with different argument gives clear view of an issue.

I've read some posts eg. [How to clear variables after each batch script run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727125/how-to-clear-variables-after-each-batch-script-run) but I think it's different kind of problem.

So, is there any way to protect against such behavior inside IF/ELSE statement?

Comment: You should ideally change `if  %1.==. (` to `If  "%~1" == "" (` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
if  %1.==. (
    echo Missing argument
) else (
    SET somevar=%1
    echo %1
    CALL echo %%somevar%%
)
```

or

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if  %1.==. (
    echo Missing argument
) else (
    SET somevar=%1
    echo %1
    echo !somevar!
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`CALL echo %%somevar%%`) [(note doubled percent signs)](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- (it's **not** `%1%` but `%1`) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)